# Creating an Array with random numbers with a specific object reference

Tags: java, arrays, object, reference

For each of the 100 elements of the calc, instantiate a Claclal object with 
randomly generated numbers. Use the Random class along with the .nextDouble() method 
for this.

I have already created the 100 elements but i cant add any numbers to the array. When i try and add any random numbers i get an error saying that it is requires a claclal but its found an int.

```
public class Claclal {

private static Claclal[] calc;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random r = new Random();
    calc = new Claclal[100];

    for (int i = 0; i <calc.length; i++) {
        calc[i] = new Claclal();
        calc[i] = (int)(Math.random());
    }
```

the error that i am getting is on the last line. 
I cant change the reference to int because its supposed to be a claclal reference. What do i need to change to get the code to work?

Comment: you have an array of `Clacal` not an array of `int`

Comment: Welcome to SO. If any of the answers help you succesfully resolves your issue, [please accept it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 1):

You have an array of `Clacal` type, not int type. You have 2 options

1st) Create a property in Clacal that is the double.

Example:

```
public class Claclal {

private static Claclal[] calc;
private  final double number;

public Clacal(double number){
  this.number=number;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random r = new Random();
    calc = new Claclal[100];

    for (int i = 0; i <calc.length; i++) {
        calc[i] = new Claclal(r.nextDouble());
    }
}
```

2nd) Make a double array

```
public class Claclal {

private static double[] calc;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random r = new Random();
    calc = new Claclal[100];

    for (int i = 0; i <calc.length; i++) {
        calc[i] = r.nextDouble();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
calc[i] = (int)(Math.random());
```

That is not allowed since array type is `Claclal`, and you are trying to insert integer.

You need to take a field in `Claclal` class and add to that.

```
 Claclal c= new Claclal();
 c.setRandomNumber((int)(r.nextDouble()));
 calc[i] = c;
```

Then your code turns

```
public class Claclal {

    private static Claclal[] calc;
    private int randomNumber;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random r = new Random();
        calc = new Claclal[100];
        for (int i = 0; i < calc.length; i++) {
            Claclal c = new Claclal();
            c.setRandomNumber((int) (r.nextDouble()));
            calc[i] = c;
        }
    }

    public int getRandomNumber() {
        return randomNumber;
    }

    public void setRandomNumber(int randomNumber) {
        this.randomNumber = randomNumber;
    }
}
```

More over you are using `Math.random()`  and you want to use `r.nextDouble()`

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because the `claclal` class doesnot have any attribute. 
Add an attribute in `claclal` as shown below:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Claclal {

    private static Claclal[] calc;
    int value;

    public Claclal( int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random r = new Random();
        calc = new Claclal[100];

        for (int i = 0; i < calc.length; i++) {
                calc[i] = new Claclal(r.nextInt());
                System.out.println(""+calc[i].value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @tawnpawt: No, it SHOULD NOT be nextDouble, it should be nextInt. If you use nextDouble and cast to int, most of the values will be 0, so your array will be filled with 0. Edited answer and used nextInt, you can check with nextDouble and see most values will be 0.

Comment: @tawnpawt: [nextDouble](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextDouble()) gives `value between 0.0 and 1.0`, when you cast it to `int`, you get 0, only when 1.0 is generated, you get 1, is that what you expect in this program? only 0's and 1's ??

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to assign an `int` value as an element of the `Claclal` array.

You should add a field to the `Claclal` class to store a double value in each object. In your `main` method, use the `Random` object that you have instantiated to pass a new random `double` value to the constructor of each new instance of `Claclal` in the array.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Claclal {
    // the double field to store a value
    private double value;

    public Claclal(double value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    // getter
    public double getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }

    // setter
    public void setValue(double value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random r = new Random();
        Claclal[] calc = new Clalcal[100];

        for (int i = 0; i < calc.length; i++) {
            // add new Claclal object with a random double value
            calc = new Claclal(r.nextDouble());
        }
    }
}
```